# Update datalabel on click of a point on the series of a highcharts timeline chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to show dataLabel of a point on click which is easy in normal line charts, but seems like it is no more case with highcharts timeline chart. Is there a workaround for this?

Here is the fiddle for normal line chart which works for enabling dataLabel on click ,

```
events: {
                    click: function() { 
          this.series.data[this.index].update({dataLabels: {enabled: true,
          useHTML: true,
          formatter: function(){
             return '<span style="color: red">sudheer</span>';
          }
          }});
         }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4zdLr70f/

Here is the fiddle for timeline chart which is not working ,

https://jsfiddle.net/zxpa8ned/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a bug in timeline series. You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

As a workaround update `userDLOptions` instead of `dataLabels`.

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function() {
            this.update({
                color: 'red',
                userDLOptions: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return 'sudheer';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sf95dy2a/

Comment: Yes, You are correct @ppotaczek , It is an issue and is been tracked here https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16084 , but this work around surely helping a lot.